# Select element in $(this) in multiple selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select an element in the following function:

```
  $('.reply-comment').live('click', function(){
if( $(this).parents('.element_footer').find('.reply, .send-reply').is(':hidden') ){
  $(this).parents('.element_footer').find('.reply, .send-reply').slideDown('fast');
}else if( $(this).parents('.element_footer').find('.reply, .send-reply').is(':visible') ){
  $(this).parents('.element_footer').find('.reply, .send-reply').slideUp('fast');
}
return false;
```

});

After: `.find('.reply, .send-reply').slideDown('fast')` i would chain a `.focus()` just to `.reply` element

How can i select it from `$(this)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> **Description:** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$(this).filter('.reply');
```